# Connecting a Hypervisor to a SAN

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, storage-area-network

This is a hypothetical scenario for my college project.

I am wondering what way to physically connect a VMWare ESXi 5 server to a SAN server.

In my scenario both computers have gigabit NIC's using CAT6 cable, the type of communication will be iSCSI.

Can my ESXi server directly connect to my SAN using a crossover cable? Or does my SAN need to connect to my network switch via a straight through cable?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The server *could* connect to the SAN using, well pretty much anything including RFC1149-style IP over Avian Carriers. Whether or not you *should* use a certain technology depends entirely on your needs and somewhat on the skill set of the administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iSCSI runs over TCP/IP which means all the normal rules of networking apply. A crossover cable would work fine.

That said, this does defeat many of the end goals of shared storage and ESXi. For example, no vMotion. As it's a homework thread, I'll let you investigate why.

Also, you remove the ability to allow other devices to see the SAN in the future.